# post_exists() in an external script?

Tags: posts

I use this code to import posts from an external script.
https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bc9d443da989c6692441

This works but I need to check if a post exits.
So I want to use post_exists().

```
if(post_exists("test") > 0) {
}
```

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function post_exists()
```

Is it possible to check in an external script for posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post_exists()` doesn't exist because you forgot to include the file where the function is declared. Looking to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/#source you can see that it's declared in `wp-admin/includes/post.php`

Add this to your existing code juste after the `require` of taxonomy.

```
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php';
```

The best way to achieve what you want is to use wp-api in my opinion !